# Retrieve data from "getDocument" query inside another "getDocument" query

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem in my code retrieving data from Firestore.

I have 2 classes in my code: Exercise and Tag.
And I have 2 collections in my FirestoreDatabase: exercises and tags

I need to fecth all the "exercise" documents from the "exercises" collection. Every "exercise" document has a field called "tags" that is an array of strings. Each string of the array contains the "id" that refers to the document that "tag" has on "tags" collection. So, querying this id in "tags" collection, enables me to get the correct "tag" document and access all its data. And this is exactly what I want to do in my code.

I need to fecth all the exercises into a Exercise object and for that I have to use a getDocument query inside another getDocument query in order to get "Tags" of the exercise from "tags" collection

This are my classes Tag and Exercise:

```
class Tag {  
var id: String?
var type: String?
var description: String?

init(id: String, type: String, description: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.type = type
    self.description = description
  }
}

class Exercise {
   let id: String?
   let group: String?
   let tags: [Tag]
   let title : String!

   init(id: String, group: String, tags: [Tag], title: String){  
    self.id = id
    self.group = group
    self.tags = tags
    self.title = title   
  }

}
```

And this is the code where I fetch my "exercises" from Firestore database:

```
func fetchExercises(completion: @escaping ([Exercise]) -> ()) {

    let exercisesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("exercises")

    exercisesRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

        var exercisesArray = [Exercise]()

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

                let myData = document.data()
                let exercise_ID = document.documentID
                let exercise_group = myData["Group"] as! String
                let tagsArray = myData["Tags"] as! [String]

                var exercise_tags: [Tag] = [Tag]()

                for tag in tagsArray {
                    let tagID: String = tag
                    fetchTagfromID(tagID: tagID) { (tag: Tag) in
                        exercise_tags.append(tag)
                    }
                }

                let exercise_title = myData["Title"] as! String                 

                exercisesArray.append(Exercise(id: exercise_ID,
                                               group: exercise_group,
                                               tags: exercise_tags,
                                               title: exercise_title,
                ))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
               print("EXERCISE FETCH HAS FINIS")
                completion(exercisesArray)
            }
        }
    }
}


func fetchTagfromID(tagID: String, completion: @escaping (Tag) -> ()) {


let tagRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("tags").document(tagID)

tagRef.getDocument() { (document, err) in

    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {

        let myData = document?.data()

        let tagDescription: String = myData!["description"] as! String
        let tagType: String =  myData!["type"] as! String
        let tag: Tag = Tag(id: tagID, type: tagType, description: 
tagDescription)


        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            print("TAGS FETCH HAS FINISHED")
            completion(tag)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My problems come with the timing (queues) code is executed.

I need to fill "exercise_tags" first (secondary getDocument query) and then continue and finish fetchExercise (main getDocument query) but Firestore do not allow (or do not know how) to do that. Code finishes first the main getDocument query (fetChExercises) and then get back to finish secondary getDocument Query (fetchTagfromID).

In summary I need that in runtime I get this log:

```
TAGS FETCH HAS FINISHED
EXERCISES FETCH HAS FINISHED
```

and now I am getting the opposite.

Do you know guys how to solve this problem? Maybe changing dispatch queing...

I now how to solve the problem doing this in two steps but elegant solution is doing everything in one step. This is, fetchExercises.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is get all tags for one Exercise then fetch another Exercise. and after all fetch call completion handler to update UI. I made some change in code you can check it.

```
   var exercisesArray = [Exercise]()
   var listFromFetchExercise = []()  //it will contain all object of array 
   querySnapshot!.documents. set DataType according to that.
   var completion_exercises_Listner: () -> ()

   func fetchExercises(completion: @escaping ([Exercise]) -> ()) {

   let exercisesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("exercises")

exercisesRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {

        listFromFetchExercise = querySnapshot!.documents
        fetchAllExercise()

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
           print("EXERCISE FETCH HAS FINIS")
            completion(exercisesArray)
        }
    }
}
}

func fetchAllExercise(completion: @escaping ([Exercise]) -> ()){

fetchExercise()
completion_exercises_Listner = {
    completion(exercisesArray);
}

}

func fetchExercise(index:Int = 0) {

  let document = listFromFetchExercise[index]

  let myData = document.data()
  let exercise_ID = document.documentID
  let exercise_group = myData["Group"] as! String
  let tagsArray = myData["Tags"] as! [String]

  var exercise_tags: [Tag] = [Tag]()

  fetchTagsFromIDS(tagsArray) { (tag: [Tag]) in
  exercise_tags.append(contentsOf: tag)

  let exercise_title = myData["Title"] as! String                 

  exercisesArray.append(Exercise(id: exercise_ID,
                               group: exercise_group,
                               tags: exercise_tags,
                               title: exercise_title,

   DispatchQueue.main.async{
      exercisesArray.append(tag)
      if (index + 1) < exercisesArray.count {
        fetchExercise(index+1,)
      }else{
        //Done
        completion_exercises_Listner()
      }

  }
   ))

  }



 var listofTags = [String]()
 var resultofTags = [Tag]()

   func fetchTagsFromIDS(tagIDS:[String],completion: @escaping (_ tags:[ 
 String]) -> ()){

listofTags = tagIDS;
fetchTagfromID() //Start With first tag

completionListner = {
    completion(resultofTags);
}

}

var completionListner: () -> ()

func fetchTagfromID(index:Int = 0) {

 let tagRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("tags").document(tagID)

 tagRef.getDocument() { (document, err) in

if let err = err {
    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
} else {

    let myData = document?.data()

    let tagDescription: String = myData!["description"] as! String
    let tagType: String =  myData!["type"] as! String
    let tag: Tag = Tag(id: tagID, type: tagType, description: 
   tagDescription)


    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        print("TAGS FETCH HAS FINISHED")
        resultofTags.append(tag)
        if (index + 1) < listofTags.count {
          fetchTagfromID(index+1,)
        }else{
          //Done
          completionListner()
        }
        //completion(tag)
    }
}
} }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I will test as soon as I can. But,meanwhile, I'd like to solve a doubt. What does your code work and mine not? I mean, from my ignorancy, I see that you have separated the process into more steps (sub-functions) but the point is the same. Which is the main difference that makes your code works and wait till all tags from exercise are fetch?

Comment: So the main different is as you mention in your question 'exercise_tags' need first then continue finishing fetchExercise method. so that what my code does. so in my code as you can see when querySnapshot!.documents fetched what i done is fetch all exercise one by one. In that when i fetch first exercise i will call fetchTagsFromIDS for fetch all Tags for exercise then and then i will go ahed for another exercise. so it will wait until all tags for exercise finish then it will fetch another exercise which you wanted in your app. Debug code the code you will understand the process.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you very much for your question. It solves the problem. However, I am sure that must be a solution that allow to do it inside the same function. I will continue investigating. Thank you.